# Comparability of a set and a subset of power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

It's well known that for any set $A$, $A < P(A)$.

But now, I have some question that, **WITHOUT AC**, can we guarantee that $A \leq X$ or $X \leq A$ whenever $X \subseteq P(A)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, we can't quite prove this.

Cohen's first model for the failure of the axiom of choice has a set of real numbers which is infinite but Dedekind-finite. This means exactly that this set has cardinality incomparable with that of $\Bbb N$.

But we know that $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality, even without assuming the axiom of choice. So in this universe of sets there is a subset of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ which is incomparable with $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Oh, it's very clear. Thank you @Asaf